# Swift3 Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Version]'

Tags: swift

Hello I am having trouble calling my methods to the controller properly as I am getting this error Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Version]'. I need help fixing this, thanks.

Swift 3 Method:

```
var versions : [Version] = []
func isActiveVersion() -> Bool {

    let api = versionAPI()
    versions = api.getVersionFromAPI(completion: ({_ in }))
    for version in versions{
        if version["version"] == "1.0.0" {
            return true

        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3 Call

```
public class versionAPI {


var versions : [Version] = []


//---------------------------------
// MARK: ENDPOINTS
//---------------------------------
let getVersionEndPoint = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/versions"


//---------------------------------
// MARK: REQUESTS
//---------------------------------

func getVersionFromAPI(completion: @escaping ([Version]) -> Void){
    let url = URL(string: getVersionEndPoint)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completion([])
            return
        }

        print(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        self.parseVersionsToJSON(data: data)
        completion(self.versions)
    }        
    task.resume()
}
func parseVersionsToJSON(data: Data) {

    do {
        self.versions = []
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
            for dic in json {
                let version = Version()
                version.version = dic["version"] as! String
                version.active =  dic["active"] as! Bool
                self.versions.append(version)
            }
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getVersionFromAPI` sets up an asynchronous task and then immediately returns before that task completes, returning `void` to its caller. This is why you get the error you report.

The `[Version]` value produced by the asynchronous task is passed by that task to the completion function passed to `getVersionFromAPI`. The completion function you pass `{_ in }` does nothing, so the list of versions is simply discarded.

You cannot simply call an asynchronous task, which will complete at some future time, from a synchronous task, `getVersionFromAPI` in your case, and have that asynchronous task somehow become synchronous and return its future result immediately.

You need to study asynchronous design. Then either redesign your code so the task done by `getVersionFromAPI` is itself asynchronous, or use one of the standard techniques to block your synchronous method from proceeding until the asynchronous one has completed.

If after revising your design you have trouble with your code ask a new question, showing your code, and someone will undoubtedly help you.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
versions = api.getVersionFromAPI(completion: ({_ in }))
```

getVersionFromAPI does not return anything. Declare a global struct then pass the data into it and use DispatchQueue when finished to post a NotificationCentre

```
do {
    GlobalStruct.versions = []
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
        for dic in json {
            let version = Version()
            version.version = dic["version"] as! String
            version.active =  dic["active"] as! Bool
            GlobalStruct.versions.append(version)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotIt"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

your Swift 3 ViewController should have the following:

```
    var versions: [Version] = []

func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFunction), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotIt"), object: nil)
    let api = versionAPI()
    api.getVersionFromAPI()
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func myFunction() {
     versions = GlobalStruct.versions
     if isActiveVersion {
           .....
     }
}
```

Comment: Im new to swift3 can you show me with code how to setup the notification observer

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the Notification call